# Solve the linear recurrence with initial conditions $a_n=a_{n-1}+2^n+1$ and $ a_0 =0$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

Let $(a_n)_{n\geq0}$ be the sequence defined by
$$a_0=0\qquad\text{and}\qquad\forall n\geq0,\ a_n=a_{n-1}+2^n+1.$$

I know this is a non-homogeneous case and so far as I have gotten the general homogeneous solution of A1(1)^n and I am having trouble with the particular solutions. I know I can split them up and solve $2^n$ and $1$ separately but every time I do I get a solution that isn't correct.

Comment: For $2^n$ try $c2^n$. For $1$, $a_n=n$ is clear.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* If we let $b_n=a_n-n$ then these have the recursion $b_n=b_{n-1}+2^n$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $a_{n-1} = a_{n-2} + 2^{n-1} +1$, so $a_n = a_{n-2} + 2^n+2^{n-1} +2$. Can you handle from here?

Comment: Yeah I should be able to do it from there, I am giving it a try now. Thank you for the hint

Comment: I am attempting to solve it and what do i do when i get to the 2^(n-1). I have been taught for $%2^n$ should be in this case $$2^n*k*n^2$$ because we have multiplicity 2. I may need a little more help

Comment: No it should be something like $n + \sum_{k=1}^{n}2^k$ which you can easily find

Answer (score 0):

You can use:
$$a_n-a_0=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(a_{k+1}-a_k)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\bigl(2^{k+1}+1\bigr)=2^{n+1}-2+n,$$
hence (since $a_0=0$):
$$a_n=2^{n+1}+n-2.$$